# Android gradle error: All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification?

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

You find dozens of questions of the same title on stackoverflow. Unfortunately none of those solved my problem.

I got following error:

All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 26.1.0, 25.3.1. Examples include `com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0` and `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1`

on this line (module app):

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$android_support_version"
```

**But I don't see why? Where do I use version 26.1.0?**

Here are my files (Project file):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        android_support_version ="25.3.1"
        archVersion = "1.0.0-alpha3"
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bsobat.github"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$android_support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:$android_support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$android_support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$android_support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$android_support_version"

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //dagger2
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9"
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'


    //android arch. component
    compile "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$archVersion"
    compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$archVersion"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$archVersion"
    compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$archVersion"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$archVersion"

    //Retrofit
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'

    //OkHttp
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.7.0'

    //Gson
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'

    //Glide
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'


    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    testCompile("android.arch.core:core-testing:$archVersion", {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-compat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-core-utils'
    })

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42374426/436938 You don't use 26.1.0, one of the libraries use it. Did you try to change `android_support_version` to 26.1.0 too?

Comment: Yes I did. Then it says: Duplicate class android.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap found in modules classes.jar (android.arch.core:core:1.0.0-alpha3) and common-1.0.0.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.0.0)
Duplicate class android.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$Entry found in modules classes.jar (android.arch.core:core:1.0.0-alpha3) and common-1.0.0.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.0.0)
Duplicate class android.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$ListIterator found in modules classes.jar (android.arch.core:core:1.0.0-alpha3) and common-1.0.0.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below code block in bottom of your app level gradle file.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Then it says: Duplicate class android.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap found in modules classes.jar (android.arch.core:core:1.0.0-alpha3) and common-1.0.0.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.0.0)
Duplicate class android.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$Entry found in modules classes.jar (android.arch.core:core:1.0.0-alpha3) and common-1.0.0.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.0.0)
Duplicate class android.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$ListIterator found in modules classes.jar (android.arch.core:core:1.0.0-alpha3) and common-1.0.0.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.0.0)